# Repository in MVVM with RxJava

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am using Android Jetpack Navigation for my project, and I have implemented the logic in the following way!
In my Mission Repository I am using this logic ->

```
public void getCurrentJobMissions() {
        missionsDisposable.add(dao.missionCount().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(integer -> {
            
if (integer == 0) {                
makeApiCallAndSaveToDBJobMissions();
            }
            
getDataFromDBJobMissions();
        }));
```

Where dao.mission count is just a

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MissionsTable")
    Single<Integer> missionCount();
```

So what I am doing here is that every time the user is entering the application , I am checking if there is any data on the database , if not -> makeApiCallAndSaveToDBJobMissions and then retrieve them from room database , if yes -> retrieve them from room database!
**This logic is working fine** but I don't think this is the best practice!
Can anyone provide me with an example of better solution to this! Thanks

Comment: To me your implementation is ok, without having additional context

Comment: Your implementation is your answer to your question :). Good job dude

Comment: You doing good but if you want to learn for more follow link:
https://github.com/mitchtabian

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I guess I'm staying with this implementation!